# Websocket closes connection with EOF exception on "101 Switching Protocols" response

Tags: android, websocket, okhttp

I'm using OKHttp3 version 3.10 on an Android application.

After a successful connection and a short period of inactivity, the OKHttp3 websocket throws an `EOFException` in response to a `101 Switching Protocols` response. This then disconnects the socket, and our application is forced to re-connect again.

Is there anyway to control this so the socket does not close?

Is this expected behavior?

Our iOS and server side tests against the same server did not show this behavior, and remained connected until the applications disconnected them explicitely.

RealWebsocket class:

```
public void connect(OkHttpClient client) { ...

   try {
        RealWebSocket.this.listener.onOpen(RealWebSocket.this, response);
        String name = "OkHttp WebSocket " + request.url().redact();
        RealWebSocket.this.initReaderAndWriter(name, streams);
        streamAllocation.connection().socket().setSoTimeout(0);
        RealWebSocket.this.loopReader();
    } catch (Exception var6) {
        RealWebSocket.this.failWebSocket(var6, (Response)null);
    }
```

(Response return code 101)

Comment: What value did editing this add ?  I could use a quality answer for this. I think it was pretty clear what the question is.

Answer (score -1):

Issue Resolved:

Apologies, I should have specified that I am also using the wonderful STOMP client on top of the OKHttp3Client websockets:
https://github.com/NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid by Nickolay Savchenko (NaikSoftware). This library does an exceptional job of implementing the STOMP protocol integrated with OKHttp3 websockets.
This is where I fell short by using the wrong StompClient.over method to provide my url, which will create a default websocket instance that has a default socket read timeout (30 seconds ?). The solution for me was to use the alternative StompClient.over method, allowing for a reference to an application instance of the OKHttp3Client. This allows the application set it's desired timeouts beyond any defaults.

Thank you to all of you who did try to assist me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. Can you be more specific with code? Where the exact change is needed? What should I change in Stomp.over method.